# Width of rollover div is different than container

Tags: html, css, scale, rollover, fluid-images

I'm having an issue getting Chrome and Safari to correctly display the rollover div above my container image. What I have done works sometimes, but when resizing the page, you can sometimes see a little gap of 1 or 2 pixels between the rollover div and the image container.

I made a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/eJNsS/9/

**Screenshot**
[image]

**HTML**

```
<div id="related_projects">
    <a href=#  ><div class="thumbnail_image_related_project"><div id="image"><img width="300" height="173" src="http://www.gulfster.com/Lessern/Gulfsterhat.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image"  /></div><h2 class="transparent_font">IMG1</h2></div></a>          
    <a href=#  ><div class="thumbnail_image_related_project"><div id="image"><img width="300" height="173" src="http://www.gulfster.com/Lessern/Gulfsterhat.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image"  /></div><h2 class="transparent_font">IMG2</h2></div></a>          
    <a href=#  ><div class="thumbnail_image_related_project"><div id="image"><img width="300" height="173" src="http://www.gulfster.com/Lessern/Gulfsterhat.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image"  /></div><h2 class="transparent_font">IMG3</h2></div></a>          
    <a href=#  ><div class="thumbnail_image_related_project"><div id="image"><img width="300" height="173" src="http://www.gulfster.com/Lessern/Gulfsterhat.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" /></div><h2 class="transparent_font">IMG4</h2></div></a>           
    <a href=# ><div class="thumbnail_image_related_project"><div id="image"><img width="300" height="173" src="http://www.gulfster.com/Lessern/Gulfsterhat.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" /></div><h2 class="transparent_font">IMG5</h2></div></a>            
    <a href=#  ><div class="thumbnail_image_related_project"><div id="image"><img width="300" height="173" src="http://www.gulfster.com/Lessern/Gulfsterhat.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" /></div><h2 class="transparent_font">IMG6</h2></div></a>           
    <a href=# ><div class="thumbnail_image_related_project"><div id="image"><img width="300" height="173" src="http://www.gulfster.com/Lessern/Gulfsterhat.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" /></div><h2 class="transparent_font">IMG7</h2></div></a>
```

CSS

```
#related_projects {
    background-color :#FFFF44;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 2%;
}
#related_projects .thumbnail_image_related_project {
    width: 23%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
}
#related_projects img {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto;
}
#related_projects p, #categories_container #left p {
    text-align: left;
    color: black;
    font-family: HermL, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 23px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#link_description {
    float: left;
    width: 98%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
}
#link_description #link {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    color: black;
    font-family: HermL, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 23px;
}
#link_description #link a {
    color: #666666;
    font-family: HermL, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
}
#link_description #link a:hover {
    color: #22B573;
    font-family: HermL, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* THUMBNAIL PICTURES
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

.thumbnail_image_related_project .transparent_font {
    line-height: 1.25em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: black;
    background-color:white; 
    width: 92%;
    padding-right: 3%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    opacity:1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
.thumbnail_image_related_project h2 {
    padding-top: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    color: black;
    font-family: HermL, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 23px;
}
h2 {
    margin:0px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#slider").hover(
    function(){
        $(".caption").stop().animate({'opacity' : '0.9'}, 200);
    },
    function(){
        $(".caption").stop().animate({'opacity' : '0'}, 100);
    }
);

$(".thumbnail_image_related_project").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).children(".transparent_font").stop()
               .animate({'opacity' : '0.7', 'padding-top': '10px'}, 300);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).children(".transparent_font").stop()
               .animate({'opacity' : '0', 'padding-top': '30px'}, 300);
    }
);
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Probably sub-pixel problem.

Comment: @Damonsson what is a sub-pixel problem?

Comment: Browser badly divided by percentages. Google turned off?

Comment: It seems fine in Chrome, or I don't understand your issue?

Comment: Does any one have any ideas how can I bypass this problem?
Useful links, example of working rollover etc.
Thanks

Comment: I'm using a mac, but, when you resize the window, some times we have this pixel gap.

Comment: This definitely looks like a pixel rounding issue. If I change the width on `#related_projects .thumbnail_image_related_project` form a percentage to a pixel value (say 200px) the issue goes away.

Comment: Yes, it is a percentage problem.  Use pixels.  The web does not do half % pixels, so when you expand, it doesn't know which whole number to round up to.  I don't understand why you are doing it this way anyways.  It seems that there's an easier way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Pixel rounding errors

The `h2` tag is not always entirely covering the image beneath it. The black line is the part of the image that's not covered. This is due to pixel rounding errors that occur when the content is scaled.

There are 2 places where a noticeable pixel rounding error is occuring:

1. The absolute positioning of the `h2` tag. Even when using `top:0; left:0`, this can still introduce a rounding error. When this happens, the `h2` is displayed at a slight offset, so that it's not lined up consistently with the `img` tag.
2. Splitting up the total width of the `h2` tag into 8% for the combined horizontal padding and 92% for the interior content. In effect, the combined % values do not always add up to 100% when scaled.

Either one of these by themselves causes inconsistent rounding errors to occur between the `h2` tag and the `img` tag. And inconsistencies between the 2 elements tend to be noticeable visually.

### Solutions

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/85zpF/)

The key concept for avoiding this inconsistency is to ensure that the `h2` tag has the exact same rounding errors as the `img` tag. There's no practical way to entirely avoid rounding errors of this sort, but as long as they're consistent between the 2 elements, they won't be noticeable in this case.

To fix #1, add `position:relative;` to the `img` tag. Any rounding errors in the relative positioning of the `img` tag will be consistent with the rounding errors in the absolute positioniong of the `h2` tag (since their positioning is relative to the same element). This essentially cancels out the rounding errors caused by the absolute positioning.

**CSS added**

```
#related_projects img {
    position: relative;
    ...
}
```

To fix #2, use one of the following approaches:

- Change the width of the `h2` tag to 100% and add `box-sizing: border-box;` (as well as the -moz- and -webkit- versions). This [won't work for IE7](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing) or earlier. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/85zpF/) using `box-sizing`.
- Remove the horizontal padding from the `h2` tag, and add a `text-indent` to simulate the left padding (if that's adequate). [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/wE697/1/) using `text-indent`.
- Remove the horizontal padding from the `h2` tag, and add a wrapper element inside or outside of the `h2` tag, with the outer element having `width:%100; position:absolute;`, and the inner element having `padding: 0 3% 0 5%;`. Typically this would be done by adding a span inside the `h2` tag.

Any of the above approaches prevent this particular rounding error from occurring. The [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/85zpF/) mentioned above uses `box-sizing`. As long as support for IE7 or earlier isn't needed, this is probably the most elegant fix for #2, and it doesn't require adding additional HTML elements.

**CSS removed**

```
.thumbnail_image_related_project .transparent_font {
    width: 92%;
    ...
}
```

**CSS added**

```
.thumbnail_image_related_project .transparent_font {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    ...
}
```

If support for IE7 or earlier is required, and `text-indent` isn't adequate, and editing the static HTML isn't an option, then use JavaScript or jQuery to inject a wrapper element.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detail answer. This fixed my problem. Note: I had a new div inside the h2 tag to indent the text as you said. Thanks again. Your bounty is coming in 4 hours =)

Comment: @Romain: I overlooked a simpler solution for issue #2: Using `width: 100%` for the `h2` tag and adding `box-sizing: border-box` (not supported by IE7 or earlier). This doesn't require adding any additional HTML elements, and it doesn't require changing the padding. I updated the answer and the demo to address this.

Comment: Both of your solutions are perfectly working, thanks a lot and nice job

Answer (score 1):

I changed your CSS a little bit and moved some CSS properties to focus your links containers within the `#related_projects`. The links didn't have 100% width and height of their contents the way you had it.

This code works for me, let me know if that's what you were looking for. You would have to fix your margins, though.

Also instead of putting the padding on the h2 tag, I changed your markup and put it on spans within the h2.

**[updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eJNsS/15/)**

Edit: the issues is fixed in Chrome, however you can still see it in Safari.

Edit2: Updated jsFiddle, I can't see the problem on my end both in Chrome and Safari

Comment: Thanks for your answer, otherwise, there are still gaps. (when, I resize the screen, we can see plenty of them).
Maybe, I need to find a different way to do it...

Comment: Updated fiddle, see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Still the same on chrome and safari on mac and pc. +1 for your help, more later